# What does flight categories "C", "G", "T" etc. mean?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-data-recorder, software

In a flight database that I'm working with on a project, there is a column of data called "flightCategory" with values "C", "G", "T", etc.  Any idea what those actually mean?  From what I understand, the database is from FAA.  But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What is the database and what other columns are there?   The context could help us.  What are the rest of the values?  Can you post the database?

Comment: Grasping at straws, I'm going to guess flight plan, and type of flight, 'G' being general aviation, 'C' I think used to be commercial, being replaced by 'S' for scheduled and 'N' for non-scheduled. But I'm not a flight plan connoisseur so I might be off the mark. Still leaves 'T' though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.  'C' is commercial, 'G' general aviation, 'T' taxi, etc.

Update:

http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/fss/AppendixA.htm, under section "Type of flight", it lists

> S  if scheduled air service
>
> N  if non­scheduled air transport operation
>
> G  if general aviation
>
> M  if military
>
> X  if other than any of the defined categories above.

But types C and T isn't there.

Comment: Without context it's hard to determine if this answer is useful (at least "useful to anyone who isn't you") -- can you tell us more about the database you're working with?

Comment: Initially I only know these abbreviated codes "C", "G", etc.  and nothing else.  Later I was told what they actually mean.  The relevant engineer dug the information up from comments in source code.

Comment: You're missing the point of *context* - ***What database is this out of?***, ***Who created/maintains it?*** etc. - without that context this question and answer aren't useful to the general public.

Comment: That, honestly, I don't know. The only thing I've been let know is the data is from FAA.

Comment: and where would you have found it? how does it look like? how is it named?